# continuous inverse function

Tags: calculus, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, continuity

> Let $V$ and $W$ be normed vector spaces and let $A$ be a compact subset of $V$. Prove that if $f : A \to W$ is continuous and injective, then $f^{-1} : f(A) \to V$ is continuous as well.

Considering a closed set $C\subseteq V$ might be useful. If $f$ is continuous, then for any sequence $(a_n)\subseteq A$ so that $a_n \to a \in A, f(a_n) \to f(a).$ I'm not sure how to show that for any sequence $(f(a_n))\subseteq f(A), f(a_n)\to f(a)\in f(A), f^{-1}(f(a_n)) = a_n \to f^{-1}(f(a)) = a$. I'm not sure why the injectivity requirement is needed either, but it may be a clue. Supposing that $a_n \not\to a$ might lead to a useful contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: For convenience let $B=f[A]$. Let $C$ be a closed subset of $A$, and suppose that $b$ is a limit point of $f[C]$; then there is a sequence $\langle b_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $f[C]$ that converges to $b$. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $a_n=f^{-1}(b_n)$. (Note that in order to do this, you need $f$ to be injective.) $C$ is compact, so $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ has a subsequence that converges to some $a\in C$. Now use the continuity of $f$ to conclude something about $b$.

Comment: So since $f$ is continuous, that means $f(a_n) = b_n \to f(a) =b$, so we must have that $a=f^{-1}(b)$,  right?

Comment: @user3472: Yes, that’s right. And that means that $b\in f[A]$ and hence that $f[A]$ is closed.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how $f(A)$ being closed, which is literally implied by $f(A)$ being compact (as $A$ is compact and $f$ is continuous) is useful. How does that show that $f^{-1}$ is continuous? In my opinion, it would be more useful to show that for any open $V\subseteq A, f(V) = f^{-1}(f^{-1}(V))$ is open as then $f^{-1}$ would have to be continuous.

Comment: @user3472: A function $g:X\to Y$ is continuous iff $g^{-1}[C]$ is closed for each closed set in $Y$. (Look at $g^{-1}[Y\setminus C]$.) Thus, $f^{-1}$ is continuous iff $f[C]$ is closed for each closed $C\subseteq A$.

Answer (score 0):

Injectivity is required in order for $f^{-1}$ to be a function, otherwise the notation $f^{-1}(w)$ may not be well-defined. As a hint, it is a good idea to look at closed subsets $C \subset A$ (not necessary to look at $V$ as a whole, since the image of $f(A)$ under $f^{-1}$ is $A$) and use the fact that $A$ is compact in order to say something about $C$ and $f(C)$.